# Best Option for GOOGLE MAPS API response (XML,JSON, KML)

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am new in iphone application development, I am making application which get direction between 2 given locations using google maps APIs..but I'm confuse that which formate to use for receiving set of coordinates XML, JSON or KML?

Answer (score 2):

I always prefer JSON over xml. I have used both xml and json but found json better as json respose is easily converted into arrays or dictionary using any JSON API.
Also you can use [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to see the content of the json.

Answer (score 1):

JSON has several advantages over XML. Its a lot smaller and less bloated, so you will be passing much less data over the network - which in the case of a mobile device will make a considerable difference.